# PHP setcookie / cookies not working

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I pulled this file from w3schools, it works perfectly fine through their editor but when I upload it on my hosting service it keeps showing up as "Cookie 'user' is not set". I checked my php.ini file and it seems like cookies are turned on, are there other settings that might be causing this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), ""); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
 echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
 echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
 echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You have a line of HTML before your PHP code. I assume output buffering is off, so this line causes the response headers to be sent. Move the first line behind the PHP code.

Comment: *facepalm* After all the answers I saw on here clearly saying to put the php code first I went ahead and made the same mistake. It's working now, thank you v. v. much!

Answer (score 1):

You might not have cookies enabled on your browser. If you are using chrome, you can try the following steps:

1. Click the menu icon on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Settings.
3. Click the Show advanced settings
4. Click Content Settings
5. In the "Cookies" section of the dialog that appears, make sure Allow
   local data to be set is selected to allow both first-party and
   third-party cookies.
6. Click Close.

If you are using another browser, just google: "Allow coockies on **[Browser Name]**"